# connection string for SQL Server 2012 on same machine

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, connection

I am running sql server 2012 on a server and I had my website running on another server. I always used a connection string like this to connect to the server:

```
connectionString="Data Source = xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx; Initial Catalog=MyDatabase; Integrated Security=false; User ID=MyUserName; Password=MyPassword"
```

but now when I moved the website to the same computer as the database, I wasn't sure what my connection string should look like so I just changed `Data Source = "127.0.0.1"` and used the localhost ip to connect to it. It works fine, but is there a better or more appropriate way to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- 127.0.0.1
- localhost
- . (dot means localhost)

All fine for connecting to local database.

Comment: so there's no difference between these 3 and they are all the same?

Comment: Yes, they are all same.

Answer (score 0):

connectionString="Data Source =.; Initial Catalog=MyDatabase; Integrated Security=false; User ID=MyUserName; Password=MyPassword"

if you use "." as your data source it means local machine

Comment: so what I did is also correct and there's no difference in using a "." vs. 127.0.0.1 ?